# problem to integrate React with Node using axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, axios

I'm creating a project with react and node, which consists of an app that adds people data to a database, in this project there is a basic front-end made with react, which is running on localhost:3000 and a back-end made with node that is running on localhost:3333.

The problem is that when I use axios in the font-end to interact (create, get or delete people from the database) with the back-end, at the click of a button, the following error appears:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3333/person/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This is my code:

```
const AddPerson = () => {
    const data = axios.post('http://localhost:3333/person/', {
        name: name,
        age: age,
        profession: profession
    })
    console.log(data)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow CORS (cross origin resource sharing)  on your server. It's not an axios problem. By default a server rejects requests that don't come from the same IP, this includes the port. Because your frontend and backend run on different ports, it looks to the backend like a "foreign" service trying to request it. This behavior is blocked by default for security reasons.

It'll depend on what your backend is, but I'll assume Vanilla Node, Next or Express

**Vanilla node**
https://bigcodenerd.org/enable-cors-node-js-without-express/

**Next**
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/api-routes-cors

**Express**
https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html